# Why am I getting dask warnings when running a pandas operation?

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a notebook with both pandas and dask operations.

When I have not started the client, everything is as expected. But once I start the dask.distributed client, I get warnings in cells where I'm running pandas operations e.g. `pd.read_parquet('my_file')`

I get exactly the number of Nanny lines as I have started workers.

Warnings example:

```
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive in Nanny for 1.26s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive in Nanny for 1.38s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive in Nanny for 1.38s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive in Nanny for 1.38s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive in Nanny for 1.37s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive in Scheduler for 1.37s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
distributed.core - WARNING - Event loop was unresponsive in Nanny for 1.36s.  This is often caused by long-running GIL-holding functions or moving large chunks of data. This can cause timeouts and instability.
```

I'd like to know why, and also how to make them stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning means that the Dask worker process was unresponsive for a longish time.  This is bad because the worker won't be able to serve data to other workers, talk to the scheduler etc.  It is not normal, even when running computations, because those computations are being run in separate threads.

There are two main causes of this problem:

1. Your tasks run functions that do not release the GIL.  This is *rare* these days (most pandas operations release the GIL) but can happen.  I *believe* that  all variants of read_parquet release the GIL
2. If this happens only once and only at startup then this was a bug that was fixed around `distributed.__version__ == '1.21.3'`.  You might want to upgrade.

You can also silence the warnings by increasing the maximum allowed tick time in your ~/.dask/config.yaml file

```
tick-maximum-delay: 10 s
```

Comment: About point 2: I do get  `'dask.distributed' has no attribute '__version__'` . What version of dask has this bug?

Comment: `import distributed; print(distributed.__version__)`

Comment: I see, `distributed` is also available as standalone package. I was confused, because there is also `dask.distributed`.

Comment: Do you know a good way to find out which function is not releasing the GIL? If this were synchronous code, throwing an exception instead of a log message would do it, but since it's async, I have no idea who is taking up that time.

Comment: Can one profile how much data is being passed around?